# Filter noisy points during interpolation

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab's interpolation feature to interpolate the values of some points inside the convex hull formed. However, some of the points inside the convex hull have noisy z value. My input points are of two dimension x & y with z giving the value at the location(x,y). In some cases the z value is particular noise value. So, how can I make sure that it doesn't affect the interpolation, I mean I don't want this value to be considered. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Define your criteria for the point to be 'too noisy'.

Too many standard deviations from the mean? (Calculate mean and standard deviation, then threshold at `n` standard deviations?)

Too different from the surrounding values? (Use a smoothing/lowpass filter.)

Some background on what this data represents, and some of its characteristics, would help here.